# Release all cached data

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm writing a navigation based application and I want to release all cached data when it is closed. If someone pushes the button on the iPad then when he started it after 5 secs I want application will start from its begining (first page) not from the last place.

Comment: You should accept answers (there will be a tick box in question posts that you own) that others have provided to the questions that you have asked - this means it is more likely others will continue to help you, as user reputation is an important part of the Stack Overflow community. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the BOOL Key "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" to your info.plist and set it to YES.
This will terminate your App when the user presses the home button